# Android - How to regenerate R class?

Tags: android, android-resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Developing for Android in Eclipse: R.java not generating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating)

I have imported a project into my Eclipse IDE, but it's giving me an error since R file is not generated automatically.

How can I edit the R file so that it matches my project requirements?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it:

When I changed manifest to target 1.5 version, million errors appeared and only one wasn't related to inexistance of R class - in manifest file attributes "targetSdkVersion" and "maxSdkVersion" did not exist in sdk 1.5

Because of this R class was not able to generate.

Comment: You should probably mark this solution as accepted.

Answer (score 47):

In  [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating), somebody answered this : you must get rid of warnings and errors (syntax and links) in your xml files. This plus doing a clean / build project.

Project -> Clean, and choose the option to build the project.

Comment: WARNING: doing a clean will most likely DELETE YOUR R CLASS. Since you have references to it all over your code which cant be found then they will result in errors. and since you cant compile with errors, no new R class will be generated!

Comment: You're supposed to delete the R class. You don't have to fix *all* the errors, just the one that R links to. E.g. if forget to close a tag in a layout called activity_page.xml (R.layout.activity_page), R will not regenerate.

Comment: if all else fails, open up a console and run: ant instrument

Answer (score 32):

I found this happening to me with a broken layout and everything blows up. Relax, it's like that old mistake when you first learned programming where you forget one semicolon and it generates a hundred errors. Many panic, press all the buttons, and makes things worse.

#### Solution

- Make sure that anything the `R.` links to is not broken. If it's broken, ADK may not regenerate R. **Fix all errors in your XML files**.
- If you somehow hit something and created `import android.R` in your activity, **remove it**.
- Run **Project -> Clean**. This will delete and regenerate R and BuildConfig.
- Make sure **Project -> Build Automatically** is ticked.
- **Wait** a few seconds for the errors to disappear.
- If it doesn't work, delete everything inside the /gen/ folder
- If it still doesn't work, try **right-clicking your project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties**.

#### What to do if R doesn't regenerate

This usually happens when you have a broken xml file.

- Check errors inside your XML files, mainly within the /res/ folder
- Common places are /layout/ and /values/ especially if you've changed one of them recently
- Check AndroidManifest.xml, I find that often I change a string, and forget to change the string name from AndroidManifest.xml.
- If you can't find the issue. **right click /gen/ -> Restore from local history... -> tick R.java -> click Restore**. This doesn't solve the problem, but it will clear out the extra errors to make the problem easier to find.

I know there's already a lot of answers here, but this is the first link on Google, so I'm compiling all the advice here and hope it helps someone else new to this :)

Comment: "Make sure that anything the R. links to is not broken". +100000

Comment: +1 for mentioning AndroidManifest.xml, I almost missed to check that file

Comment: In my case the problem was that Android Studio automatically added following import "import android.R" in activity class. All references from R were broken no matter of clean and rebuild. After removing the line the build was working again.

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem where the R.java file was not being regenerated after I'd added some icons and layout files.  I tried cleaning and rebuilding and things got worse since then the original R.java file was gone and still wasn't regenerated.  Eventually it dawned on me that there must be compiler errors for the compiler that generates R.java and we aren't being shown those in the console.  Fortunately, I had noticed earlier that

1. it's an error if one .xml file refers to another which is non-existent and
2. it's an error to have upper case letters in your file names (why is that forbidden, I LOVE camel case).

Anyways, after renaming my icons and .xml files to all lowercase and then fixing all the references inside the .xml files, voila, R.java was regenerated.  Just in time to feel good when I stopped for lunch :-)

Comment: +1 for answering in style (love the `Just in time to feel good when I stopped for lunch :-)`). But surely, R.java is causing similar trouble right now!

Comment: Images with upper case letters cause this error too

Answer (score 8):

To generate the R file again:

1. Modify something in layout->activity_main.xml
2. Save the file
3. Project->Clean...

Just delete the R file located in gen directory, and then try Project->Clean.
Then build your app again.

Answer (score 7):

You can also right click on the `project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties`.  That should cause the R.java class to be re-generated.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't do the job.

Answer (score 5):

I reopen eclipse, edit one of my xml files and then discover that my activy class was refering android.R instead of my package "R" :-)

Comment: +1. I just pick the first quick-fix I see in Eclipse and move on. This one is sneaky.

Answer (score 4):

My problem was in Manifiest file.
I have deleted launcher icons and did not reference the new ones on Manifiest :)

Comment: I had the same problem, manifest file had an error which stopped everything from proceeding.

Answer (score 4):

In order to regenerate the R.class, you will have to try multiple techniques.

- Remove any R imports from your java source files: `import R.android`
- Make sure to open the "Problems" panel by going to Window->Show view->Problems
- If you do have some errors in your xml resources, you will need to correct those errors. In my case I had to change my id attributes to include the "+" sign as follows: `android:id="@+id/grp_txt"`
- Now proceed to do Project->Clean
- Finally do Project->Close, Project->Open

The "+" sign indicates a new resource id and the forces the aapt tool to create a new resource integer in the R.java class.

Comment: It is 2018 almost 2019 and your comment just ended 3 days of work trying to figure out what is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Intellij IDEA you can click Build - Rebuild Project

Answer (score 2):

If you accidently deleted your R in eclipse by "project clean" (don´t do this)
Rightclick on your Projectfile -> Restore from local History...

recreate your R

My Case:

- Broken xml caused bug in R. (because of ä, ö, ü, letters in id)
- clean project deleted my R.

What I Did:

- recreated R from local History
- checked for wrong R imports in my classes (like import android.R) and removed them
- fixed that xml file and saved its content in an external txt file
- deleted the xml completely from my project.
- ran my project one time
- put that fixed xml back at its place

and...

- gave my girlfriend a big hug without a reason after freaking out like a Hulk.

Comment: I'm in a similar boat-- I inherited a large codebase that was already a combination of two fairly large projects and dozens of /res files.  Backing up the xml files outside Eclipse, re-building the project, and then adding xml back one at a time did the trick.  Wish I had a girlfriend to hug :s

Answer (score 2):

My problem was errors in my XML files.  Errors aren't always automatically detected in the Android Common XML Editor or Android Common Manifest Editor, so try using the regular text editor instead.  For example, somehow some random gibberish from a .java file had been inserted into my manifest and strings.xml files.

Right click on any XML files (most likely in the /res folder or AndroidManifest.xml) and click "Open With," then select "Text editor."  Make sure everything looks good and then save.  Also, make sure to enable "Build Automatically" for your project.  I had deleted my R.java file and it was rebuilt from scratch, so no need to restore it from local history.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a new "Android XML file" to, for example, the `/res/layout` folder. This might cause the plugin to to regenerate the `R` class.

Comment: Tried this, but nothing happened (I even restarted Eclipse before adding the xml file)

Comment: Added test.xml in the layout folder, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

You can just modify any xml files in /res folder and even just add a space and save, it will be regenerated.

Comment: I used to do this, but now it doesn't work... Still no R class..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem  - "R" missing. And none of the advices given here helped. Fortunately, I've found the reason - somehow Eclipse got lost the Project-Properties-target. It was unset. I don't know till now, what had done it, but setting it back helped. 
So, attention - **missing R can mean the missing target**, too!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all the solutions above. But they unfortunately it did not solve my problem. 
My R.java was gone as soon as I pasted a new picture to my drawable folder. 
After reading the answers for this question I tried to **delete** the icon I have **previously pasted** (while Build Automatically Enabled) and everything was fine afetr. Hope this will help someone!

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem and I just right-clicked on packet of my project and Build Project. Instantly the class R appeared in packet gen.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else finds this thread when Googling, like I did:

I had what appeared to be the same problem for a while, and after some digging I noticed that the R.java file got correctly built, but was ignored for only **one** of my source files. The problem for this particular file was that Eclipse had "helpfully" added the following line at the top:

```
import android.R;
```

That effectively hides the project R stuff. Just remove it and everything will be fine again...

Comment: adding this will cause your program to malfunction, if the R class is imported directly anywhere by eclipse this import state should be deleted i.e. import android.R or my_project.R (sometimes eclipse does this automatically)

Comment: Jonas is correct. The import line should be removed, as he says.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Eclipse's "Restore from local history" to restore your old R file if it has been deleted. After that you possibly see what keeps Eclipse from building your files (I've seen other errors than before which really helped fixing the problem).

Answer (score 1):

May be you can go to project properties and select Android option and then define the target for the project. Once you apply the selected target API for this project, it will automatically generate R.java.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly a problem with an invalid layout file.
Open the 'Problems' view and look for erros in XML layout files. Fix them and the R class will be recreated.

In my case there wasn't a real error. The problem view showed an error in a xml layout. The editor showed the xml error too. Just reformatting the xml using the auto formatter with  'ctrl-f' 'fixed' the xml 'error' and the R class was recreated.

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete the R.java file from your project and it will regenerate assuming you have build automatically enabled. If you do not have build automatically enabled simply goto project->build all

Comment: Sorry I didnt read correctly!

Comment: That simply isn't the case, at least on my machine.

Comment: This question was asked when android was in version 1.6, may have changed since then! But eclipse used to auto generate the file.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a String value Resource not being defined … after I added it by hand to Strings.xml, the R class was automagically regenerated!

Answer (score 0):

This problem normally happens when importing from an existing project. Try to fix all errors from all **.xml** files in **res** folder, as well as **Manifest** file. Most likely the errors are shown at "**match_parent**" parameter, change it to "**fill_parent**". When all errors are clear, R.java will be appeared.

If there is no error on any .xml file. Try edit any xml file (like delete a letter and type it back) and then save the file, this will cause to generate the R.java.

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem that the `findViewById(R.id.edit_text)` but return a TextView not a EditText. I think the problem is the R.id class has wrong id number, then, i clean the project then its works fine.

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was an improperly named XML file that caused my R file not to rebuild. This did not show up in the package explorer, but it was shown in the LogCat. Look out for any warnings there about your res files. No matter how many times you clean your project, the R file will not rebuild until those errors are taken care of.