# R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version

Tags: android, eclipse

I have the emergency live tracker sample apk file. So I run that application via eclipse.

I am getting an error.

Comment: First clean your project

Comment: what modification are you making?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magic behind R.java file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048415/magic-behind-r-java-file)

Comment: what error? can you paste it in your question?

Answer (score 9):

Just clean your project and then rebuild it. That will automatically generate a new R file.

Answer (score 2):

I had that problem and it turned out to be some weird side-effect of me not using the proper Java compiler: I used to use 1.5 for earlier SDK versions but I had to use Java 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on Project->Bulid Path->Configure Build Path ther you see error android-support-v4.jar remove this library and add library again this works fine for me.