# Continually printing "R.java was modified manually" to Console

Tags: android

After everything running normally for a few weeks, we're suddenly getting the following message printed in Eclipse's Console every few seconds.

> R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!

The project still compiles and runs normally but seems to take a little longer than usual. Cleaning and rebuilding doesn't help the issue. The R file is getting generated correctly and no other errors are showing up throughout the project. The problem is present on both developers' machines.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? Everything I could find deals with the R file not being generated. Thanks!

Comment: Fisrt of all make sure you are putting a new question which is not on SO. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048415/magic-behind-r-java-file, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427008/r-java-was-modified-manually-reverting-to-generated-version

Comment: http://www.google.co.in/search?rlz=1C1_____enIN421IN421&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=R.java+was+modified+manually!+Reverting+to+generated+version!

Comment: Like I said, everything I can find deals with the R file *not* being generated. Mine is being generated and everything works fine, it's just the hundreds of error messages I'm getting that is concerning me.

Comment: Do you have the R file checked into a code repository or open in Eclipse at all?  If it is open and you change it manually (be it yourself or a save action reformats the file or something) that might cause it.

Comment: Neither of the gen or bin folders are checked in. I had thought the same thing with the save actions but I've ensure it's stayed closed. What really gets me is our other developer is seeing the same issue so I'm sure it's related to the project setup or a bad file. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that was an odd one. One of our developers accidentally checked in a version of the .project file that included a builder that was incompatible with the Android SDK. Even after finding that and removing the entry we still had to open the project's Properties > Builders and disable/reenable any of the builders in order for it to take effect. Restarting eclipse (or even my machine) wasn't enough.