# after downloading code from SVN, how to have the auto-generated java files in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, tortoisesvn, google-code, r.java-file

I downloaded a google code through SVN , then I opened it in Eclipse but the Auto-generated Java files i.e. R.java are not being created. 
How to solve the issue.Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Developing for Android in Eclipse: R.java not generating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating)

Answer (score 1):

Building the project should be enough

Comment: Try cleaning the project and then building.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you are checking out the project from the correct level. It has to be at the project level that it was created at or Eclipse will not know it is a Java project.

For example: Projects > MyProject1 > src

Dont check it out at Projects, check it out at MyProject1