# Make a simple android button

Tags: android

I am trying to make a button. I am always getting a R.id error.

```
"id cannot be resolved or is not a field."
```

This line throws the error:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
```

Every time i try to use something with R.  it throws that same error.

If i create a field in R.java class which eclipse recommends

```
public static Object id;
```

Then, eclipse highlights  .layout1

and the error said "layout1 cannot be resolved or is not a field."

Here is the code:

```
import android.widget.Button;

Button myButton = new Button(this);
myButton.setText("Press Me");

Finally add the button to the layout:

LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
layout.addView(myButton);
```

Any help is much appreciated. Is there a way to drag and drop controls? and why cant i ever use R.id?

Comment: Have you created a "Android Project" in eclipse?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i am doing. i can do text.

Comment: Then could you check whether you have added id for your LinearLayout?

Comment: I got it working. I am new to android and i didnt have the id correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the XML definition of your layout, does it have the attribute “android:id="layout1"”? That’s how you give names for your widget IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Your R doesn't seem to be updated or generated correctly.

R is auto generated by Eclipse if you set up your project as an Android Project. It will inspect your  XMLs and generate the resource IDs for you so you could use it in your code. If you have setup your project as an Android project, try Project->Clean and see if there is any error. If there is no error during the Build, the R class with all its fields should be generated for you.

See this [SO Question - Developing for Android in Eclipse: R.java not generating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating) as well for additional help.