# R.java file not generated automatically Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Developing for Android in Eclipse: R.java not generating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating)

[image]I cleaned my project and changed my project files name.I am getting "R cannot be resolved to a variable".When i clean the project nothing happens and my /gen/ folder is still empty.I was trying to show u guys an image of the situation but unfortunately i cant due to my low reputation. I hope this can be helpful.

Comment: how about now? you should be able to post an image now

Comment: its saying : We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: There are probably errors in your resources, check them carefully and resolve all the problems there. After that the R.java should be generated.

Comment: but @Egor there is no sign of a red cross in my 'res' folder.

Comment: I upvoted your question so that you have more than 10 reputation - you should be able to post the image now.
You also should have a look into the console - most likely you have an error in your resources and that should show up there.

Comment: I had this bug before. I did exactly what you did. Hmm... Don't  remember how it got fixed. Do me a favour and post a pick on the gen>your package>R.java. See if the generated (File).xml is in there.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Typically if the R .* can not be generate means that you have some issue into the res/ folder. Check for errors in res/ folder.

> Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]

all the res/* filename should be named with lowercase character, underscore and number between 0 and 9

Comment: but the res/folder does not show any cross is there a possibility of an error without a red cross in the folder also ??

Comment: look the eclipse console. you should find "Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.] "

Comment: i changed my xml files name in the res/folder before the error occured.As you can see i've changed the main.xml to Mz_Sms_SearchOptions.xml is that causing the problem? but i tried renaming it to main.xml again it doesnt work

Comment: you can name it mz_sms_searchoptions.xml but not Mz_Sms_SearchOptions.xml .

Comment: i did that but that did'nt help

Comment: I see. check the eclipse console for this kind of the error. Of course the same rule apply to the other res/ folder

Comment: oh yeah its showing the uppercase lowercase errors in the console but they are already solved. Now the only problem is that my R.java is also created but I am not able to access my xml like this R.layout.mz_smssearchoptions

Comment: that s another issue. Try to resolve. if you can not open a new post

Comment: @blackbelt Sir : Take a look please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602559/how-do-implement-this-in-android

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your layout files contain uppercase letters, which is prohibited. You can use only lowercase letters and the "_" symbol (not sure about numbers). Change the filenames and clean your project. Hope this helps.

Comment: I changed my filenames to lowercase but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Did you rename your Application Package?  To do that, right-click your prject in the "Package Explorer" and expand "Android Tools" then click "Rename Application Package".

Comment: srt but @davehale23 how would that help?

Comment: @Mj1992 can you please tell how the issue is resolved.

Comment: it is caused due to the error in one of you `res/folder` files.Make sure all your xml files are in lower case letters.Or see the answer above I've mentioned as correct.Then clean the project in the end after resolving these errors.

Answer (score 1):

Did you change your package names as well?  If so you need to remember to update that in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: i changed my package name in AndroidManifest.xml and showed up the R.java file thnx but still when i do R.layout instead of the showing me the xml files like R.layout.mz .... it shows android.R....

Comment: Have you imported android.R into the java file?

Comment: actually it is not picking up my xml files in my layout folder. I removed the wrong package import at the top it goes to R.layout but after that does not show me my xml file like R.layout.myfile.xml

Comment: After making sure that everything is imported correctly try doing a clean.

Comment: everything is fine but i dont know why it is not giving men the option for R.layout.mz_searchoptions.xml instead of that it is showing me android.R.layout.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try a wild guess. Right click your project > properties> Builders> Make sure everything is checked.

Reason for this is because the builder found under properties is also responsible for generating the res items in the gen folder.

Answer (score 1):

Were you trying to use the Compatability libraries? Or any extra libraries at all (beyond the standard Android(SDK version).jar?

I ask because I recently had this problem, but it was all related to the libraries I had added. I'd be glad to go into more depth if so.

Comment: no i did not include any libraries

Comment: i did first it was not giving me any problem but sonner i move to v7-appcompat  it start giving me error of duplicate sha i deleted the v4 jar file and that error gone but after that R file is not generating no spelling issue on any of resource directory than what's the problem

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at what package your gen -> R.java is in.  your Activities need to be in the same package.

Package Exporer should look somthing like this.

src -> com.foo.bar -> file1.java

gen -> com.foo.bar -> R.java

Comment: yeah the package names are same.thnx btw issue is resolved.