# How Do Implement This In Android

Tags: android

I am new in Android.Can anyone tell me What type of Technology it is ? I want to add this feature in password field. May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?Can you help me with any code or a link to a guide on how to implement this correctly?

Comment: Buttons with circle background and relativelayout. And for the top a circle empty view which is filled with the code

Comment: Is there any link/Tutorials for this ? @MarcoAcierno

Comment: i think 10 buttons in rel. layout below a rel.layout with 4 rounded images.. then first passcode cliked then change image of 1st btn in 1st rel layout.. repeat it 4 times

Comment: for the top pins of images, create LinearLayout with orientation horizontal and add four `ImageView`s in it. and for the keys, create a `GridView` with items count equal to 12 and return `ImageView`s in `getView()`, return `ImageView`s with transparent images for positions of 9 and 11...

Comment: @GopalRao Sir is there any demo/tutorial for this ?

Comment: @Amiya There will be no tutorial for your particular requirements... Just you need to be aware of layouts

Comment: @GopalRao Sir : Please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22633345/value-is-not-getting-set-when-click-second-time

Comment: Just to add, this is not in accordance with android design guideline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many possibilities to create this kind of layout:

- A parent `RelativeLayout`, a `LinearLayout` with 4 dots at the top and for the bottom display your views with [the attributes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html#Position) as toLeftOf, toRightOf, etc. - make an `onClickListener` method to change their state and save the number.
- Multiple `LinearLayout`s with `weight` attributes to fill the entire space and each of the views (rounded number) fill the space *(see the example below to understand the weight attribute)* - or several `RelativeLayout`s - or even a `TableLayout`.
- Or `LinearLayout` and `GridView` below with an `ItemClickListener` method..

According to the comments below your question, there is a lot of possibilities. I choose one of them with Linear and RelativeLayout. It might be something like this:

```
<!-- named activity_main.xml -->
<RelativeLayout
    ... >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contain"
        ... android:layout_width="250dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4" >
        <!-- weightSum to 4 = whatever the screen, display 
             my children views in 4 sections -->
        <View
            ... android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/green_dots" />
        <!-- weight to 1 = this takes one section -->
        <View
            ... android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/green_dots" />
        <!-- weight to 1 = this takes one section -->
        <View
            ... android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/green_dots" />
        <View
            ... android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/green_dots" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/contain" ... >
        ... Here display your buttons (or textviews) with 
            custom drawable background for each one
</RelativeLayout>
```

And in your `Activity` class, it implements `OnClickListener` like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener { }
```

Then in your methods inside this Activity:

```
// init your buttons var
Button one, two, three, four, five ...;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // set the layout above
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // init your buttons
    one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    ... etc.

    // set them to your implementation
    one.setOnClickListener(this);
    two.setOnClickListener(this);
    three.setOnClickListener(this);
    ... etc.
}

// call this function when one button is pressed
public void onClick(View view) {
    // retrieves the id of clicked button
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
             methodToSaveNumber(int);
        break;
        case R.id.button2:
             methodToSaveNumber(int);
        break;
        case R.id.button3:
             methodToSaveNumber(int);
        break;
        ... etc.
    }
}
```

Then in your `methodToSaveNumber` method:

```
// finally, your method to save the number of the password
public void methodToSaveNumber(int i) {
    ... do something. 
    ... change the state of the buttons, the dots, whatever you want
}
```

And just to show you how it works, the drawable `green_dots` might be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <!-- radius -->
    <corners
        android:radius="20dp" />
    <!-- border -->
    <stroke 
        android:color="@android:color/green"
         android:width="2dp" />
    <!-- background (transparent) -->
    <solid 
         android:color="#00000000" />
</shape>
```

You must to inform you about the [layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) and how it works, the [click event and its listener](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#EventListeners), the [drawables and their states](http://www.charlesharley.com/2012/programming/custom-drawable-states-in-android/) (focused, pressed, disabled, ...), and finally, I hope you will get what you want.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for Answer. I want to add your approach .

Comment: Glad to help. Not sure if it's the best one but this might be a good start and I think it's the easy one when you begin.

Comment: I think you already have an answer @IntelliJAmiya :) Use the SharedPreferences, save the activities states and retrieve them when you reopen the app, on the first activity (A). It should work and it's not hard to do.