# Android adb not found

Tags: android, linux, adb

When I run my android app from eclipse, I get this error.

```
Unexpected exception 'Cannot run program "/home/antz/Development/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=2 No such file or directory' while attempting to get adb version from /home/antz/Development/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

COPY PASTE FROM Eclipse Error

```
[2012-11-26 13:43:08 - adb] Unexpected exception 'Cannot run program "/home/antz/Development/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory' while attempting to get adb version from '/home/antz/Development/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools/adb'
```

However my adb is exactly in the location where it says it's not.

What is wrong and how do I fix this?

I cd into the directory where adb is (`/home/antz/Development/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools/`) and I typed in adb and it says

```
antz@antz-90X3A:~/Development/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools$ ls  
aapt  aidl  dexdump  fastboot  llvm-rs-cc  renderscript  
adb   api   dx       lib       NOTICE.txt  source.properties  
antz@antz-90X3A:~/Development/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools$ adb  
bash: /home/antz/Development/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools/adb: No such file or directory
```

adb is green which means its an executable, correct?

for example, dx is also green and when I typed in dx into the command prompt, it works... whats wrong with adb?

Comment: Are you sure it is `platform-toolds` and not `platform-tools`?

Comment: /home/antz/Development/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-toolds/adb   THERE is an unneeded "d" in there!

Comment: sorry thats a typo by me on this post

Comment: have you checked the permissions of the file/folder? You are working on linux, make sure your user can actually access that folder and run adb

Answer (score 143, accepted):

On Linux, Android SDK `platform-tools` package containing `adb` used to be `32bit`. It worked fine on `32bit` systems. But on `64bit` systems you need to manually install the IA32 library.

For Debian based distributions try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5
```

But since v24.0 `platform-tools` contains only `64bit` binaries - so `32bit` libraries no longer required.

Comment: thanks this made it work. why didnt they include this step into the tutorial?

Comment: Google did provide the information. See http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

Click on Information for other platforms and then troubleshooting ubuntu.

Comment: yeah i was following that website. but i didnt go into troubleshooting ubuntu. anyways thanks!

Comment: @RobinChander, funny that the [Linux 64-bit ADT bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) comes with a 32 Bit adb under `adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools/adb` ... This is also a problem under other distributions, e.g. Fedora 17.

Comment: I cannot install IA32 libs! Why?

Comment: I got the same error and then I did apt-get install ia32-libs but now how do I restart the configuration of the ADT tools in eclipse? I am running Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @ afterimagedesign. Proceed the statement with Sudo to perform the activity as a super user if you can. To do so you will need a super user password.

Comment: Saved my computer from going out a window. Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Answer (score 112):

You can no longer install ia32-libs, so you must the individual 32 bit libraries needed by adb

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5
```

And for Ubuntu 13.10:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32z1
```

Comment: Is this referring to a specific version of Linux? If so, could you put it in your answer.

Comment: Note: if installation fails (bad dependences) try installing it throw the aptitude. It would suggest you to downgrade some of librares so the installation will success.

Comment: I also needed to install lib32z1 (Ubuntu 13.10)

Comment: E: Package 'lib32stdc++6' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'lib32gcc1' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package lib32ncurses5

Comment: Worked fine on Debian Jessie.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit machine, the first command worked. A dependency lib32tinfo5 was also installed automatically. I had tried the second command(the one for Ubuntu 13.10) initially, but it did not work because lib32z1 was not found.

Comment: getting error in  for 13.04 E: Unable to locate package lib32stdc++6
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lib32stdc++6'
E: Unable to locate package lib32gcc1
E: Unable to locate package lib32ncurses5
E: Unable to locate package lib32z1

Answer (score 30):

You have to install the 32 bit glibc:

in Fedore 64 bit machine

```
# yum install glibc.i686
```

This removes the misleading 'no such file or directory' message when trying to execute a 32 bit binary. With that the 64 bit Fedora system is capable of executing 64 bit binaries.

This also removes the misleading 'not a dynamic executable' message of ldd when calling ldd on a 32 bit dynamic executable.

Now you have to install missing 32 bit libraries the binaries under adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools are linked against:

```
# yum install zlib.i686 libstdc++.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 libgcc.i686
```

Thats it.

Comment: Good to see a solution for the Fedora users!

Answer (score 24):

I'm using **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit** and the following code **works for me**;

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32z1-dev
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

---

Summary:

After I tried *[apt-get install ia32-libs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13571288/1461060)*, but apt package tool suggest that;

```
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source.

However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
```

Then the above code works for me.

Comment: I tried your solution but still the problem occurs with me.

Comment: Worked for a Ubuntu 16

Answer (score 9):

This works great in Ubuntu 13.04 64bit version

You can no longer install ia32-libs, so you must the individual 32 bit libraries needed by adb

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5
```

Comment: Tested. Works great on 13.04 64bit. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: On my Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit machine, a dependency lib32tinfo5 was also installed automatically.

Answer (score 8):

On Arch linux:

Enable the "multiarch" repositories in /etc/pacman.conf

then run:

```
root@box#pacman -Syu

root@box#pacman -S lib32-glibc lib32-zlib lib32-libstdc++5 lib32-ncurses lib32-gcc-libs
```

Comment: This worked for me. It's the `multilib` repository one has to enable though.

Answer (score 4):

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and this command is the only thing that worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32z1-dev
```

Once I ran that from a command line, I was able to get the R.java file to generate (the tell-tale sign that something in your Android SDK tools installation is not quite right) by doing a Project > Clean in Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

On Fedora 17 or 18:

```
sudo yum install redhat-lsb.i686
```

Answer (score 3):

For multiarch Debian 7.0, add:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

Comment: This appears to having nothing to do with the question.

Comment: It works. But it's enough with the packages libc6:i386 and libstdc++6:i386

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the ia32-libs (IA32 libraries) package for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

I did it in my Linux Mint 12:

```
   chmod +x PATH/adb
```

Answer (score 2):

if you're having this problem in 64bits, try this (worked for me):

```
$ apt-get install lib32gcc1 libc6-i386 lib32z1 lib32stdc++6
$ apt-get install lib32ncurses5 lib32gomp1 lib32z1-dev lib32bz2-dev
$ apt-get install g++-multilib
```

http://sixarm.com/about/ubuntu-apt-get-install-ia32-for-32-bit-on-64-bit.html

Answer (score 2):

From the [Ubuntu Multiarch HOWTO](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO):

> Some users using the Android SDK might encounter problems when trying to run build-tools or platform-tools on amd64 bit platform. As replacement for ia32-libs, users should be fine just installing the following libraries:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
aptitude update
aptitude install libstdc++6:i386 libgcc1:i386 zlib1g:i386 libncurses5:i386
```

Answer (score 1):

Install these libraries in linux *apt-get install ia32-libs*

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands below. Its worked for me

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Answer (score 1):

in ubuntu 64 bits [12.04]-[14.10] and Elementary OS 64 bits

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's just a matter giving sdk files the necessary permissions.

```
sudo chmod -R +x /path/to/android-sdk-linux
```

Restart Android Studio and see if that fix it.

Permission issues typically occur when you copy/move sdk files from a NTFS partition or copying from another computer.

Answer (score 1):

> sudo apt install adb

adb not installed in your pc

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

http://abhinavasblog.blogspot.sg/2013/10/working-with-ubuntu-1304-and-1310-java.html

the blog explain resolution to Ubuntu 13.10 for installing Chrome, Java and Fixing Android SDK.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Just for the future, the answer is already given. [See this meta article.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

The correct *current* combo for Arch Linux is as follows: :

*[This part is unchanged]* Uncomment the following section in `/etc/pacman.conf`:

```
...
[multilib]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
...
```

Then:

```
sudo pacman -Syu && sudo pacman -S multilib/lib32-libstdc++5 multilib/lib32-zlib
```

The difference with the other answer is that package names include the *multilib/* part now.

(from Arch Wiki: [Multilib#Enabling](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multilib#Enabling), [Android#Troubleshooting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Android#aapt:_No_such_file_or_directory))