# R file not Genering in newly built hello world application

Tags: android, android-layout, r.java-file

I've just installed elipse on my **ubantu 13.04** ,but there seems to be a problem ,whenever i make a new project it does not generate the R file for it , i've not yet even touched any part of the code neither in XML nor in java ,so human error is not the catch here.

I've already tried follwing solutions

1. Check for errors in XML and Manifest .
2. check if Sdk-platform tools and SDk-tools are installed or not

still i cant get the r file generated ,Help please

Well a new turn has come through , maybe the reason is following 
what i've figured till now is , my ADB is not working properly, basically i've got an error in error log notifying the following:

> Unexpected exception cannot run program "/home/apadmin/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb" :error=2 , no such file or directory while attempting to get adb version from "/home/apadmin/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb"

and adb is located in the same place i've checked it and its running too i've checked it through terminal . now what I need to know is

1. how to set the path for adb in eclipse running on ubantu 13.04

Comment: Try to clean a project and look at output in "Console"

Comment: @Khay Have you updated you ADT ?

Comment: Yea i've recently updated my ADB , @GrisHu what do you think about this

"Unexpected exception cannot run program "/home/apadmin/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb" :error=2 , no such file or directory while attempting to get adb version from "/home/apadmin/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb"

I'm pretty sure the adb is all ok ,

Comment: On Linux you need to install `IA32` library as well.
Try this: `apt-get install ia32-libs` Check out thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571145/android-adb-not-found

Comment: yea that's a good thought man ,thanks, but 2 things are there , ia32 is depreceated since 12.04 and its should be 
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

and for people on ubantu 13.04  use this command
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5

Answer (score 1):

try this :

right click on your `project->properties->android-> check for project build target`.if nothing selected then check one at least.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured the problem ,thanks to People out here .

ubantu need some additionaly libraries like ia32-libs , for ubantu 12.04 and less , and the command is

```
`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`
```

and needed these libraries for Ubantu 13.04  libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5

and the command to install it is

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project name and then click on `Build Project`

Answer (score 0):

Just do one thing, in Eclipse click on Project menu and clean your project and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You might have an error in your xml. Double check it because that's why is not generating your R file somethimes.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse i've tried all tha basics ,like

1. checking the xml and manifest.

2.cleaning the project.

3.check if libraries are loaded in for build path .

what i've figured till  now is , my ADB is not working properly, basically i've got an error in error log notifying the following:

Unexpected exception cannot run program "/home/apadmin/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb" :error=2 , no such file or directory while attempting to get adb version from "/home/apadmin/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb"