# Cann't get adt to work properly

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

I wanted to work with ADT in ubuntu 13.10 but I'm having so many problems.
First I installed Eclipse to get java and eclipse both installed. Next I downloaded ADT Bundle for my os and launched it. It couldn't find Emulator file and ADB file.
So I started looking around and found an article saying that I should set enviroment path using .bashrc file. [Link to the article](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2013/10/17/how-to-install-eclipse-android-adt-bundle-on-ubuntu-13-10-saucy-unity-3264bit-step-by-step-visual-guide/).
I did that too and still I can't get it to work properly. When I try to launch an app, an error will come up saying it can't find ADB and when I try to launch avd it says it can't find emulator. And also i have trouble in my code.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

The error says:

> R cannot be resolved to a variable

And I imported android.R but another error showed up.

> activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field

I don't know what to do next. Please show me the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get adb to work, try this [Android adb not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571145/android-adb-not-found). This is the official documentation http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html