# Android bundle sdk manager - (ADT bundle doesn't recognise my path on ubuntu)

Tags: android, ubuntu, sdk, path

I'm trying to install ADT bundle (Android development kit) to my ubuntu 13.04ı download my bundle and I wanted to add some PACKAGES from Android SDK manager then it gave me an error that

> Stopping ADB server failed (code -1). Unable to run 'adb': Cannot run program "/home/mehmet/Android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory. Starting ADB server failed (code -1).

but I checked that my directory is correct

to solve it I opened the terminal and wrote

```
cd /home/mehmet/Android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools/
```

then press enter.

and it gave me this

ls adb api fastboot NOTICE.txt source.properties systrace mehmet@Hiko-comp:~/Android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools$ –

Comment: do you have the 32bit libs installed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android adb not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571145/android-adb-not-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok ıt ıs all about
downloadıng  32bit libs if youre using 64 bit computer and downloaded x64 android bundle than you need to download 32bit libs too