# Android adb is not found on Linux - also ia32-libs cannot be install to make it work

Tags: android, linux

I've installed Android SDK on Linux (elementary OS Luna).
I've received the message:
[image: Screen Shot]

Some instruction is to intall ia32-libs. But I cannot install it due to broken dependencies and the system report "unmet dependencies" and "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages".
How can I solve the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try using :

```
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

if that doesn't works refer to
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571145/android-adb-not-found)