# Java, Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: java, command

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "yarn": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
    at com.Main.main(Main.java:32)
```

Hi there, I have a weird problem when execute a command using Java. I used the following code to run a command, if I run `mkdir testFolder`, the program run successful, but if I changed the command like `yarn -v`
then error happen.

```
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("yarn -v");//, null, new File("/Users/macos/Desktop/TestProj/"));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

P/s: In debug mode: IntelliJ could run above code, but Netbeans failed.

In production mode (jar file): IntelliJ failed too.

**Edit 2:**

```
  MACs-MacBook-Pro:~ macos$ which pwd
    /bin/pwd
    MACs-MacBook-Pro:~ macos$ which mkdir
    /bin/mkdir
    MACs-MacBook-Pro:~ macos$ which java
    /usr/bin/java
    MACs-MacBook-Pro:~ macos$ which yarn
    /usr/local/bin/yarn
```

I found that if I run a command that is in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`, the code run ok (pwd, mkdir, java -version ...), but yarn is in `/usr/local/bin/`, so it didn't work, and I still don't know how to fix.

Comment: Do you have `yarn` installed on your machine?

Comment: Have you tried separating the executable from its parameters? I don't know if that is an issue when using `Runtime`, but it is when using a `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: @vahdet yarn is installed and I can run that command using command line

Comment: @deHaar remove -v but still failed :(

Comment: OK, the you have excluded one cause of error... at least.

Comment: To understand why it runs from command line, but does not from `java` compare the path that is passing to `exec` syscall when running from cmd and java correapondingly. Use `strace`.

Comment: @SomeName I just have a search for `strace`, but it may unavailable on mac

Comment: Ah, sorry. Did not take that into account... Probably there should be another tool for mac to trace system calls, but unfortunately I cannot suggest anything since I dont use mac.

Comment: thanks @SomeName, I will try to find something similar to do that

Comment: in your command line did you run yarn using sudo or without sudo?

Comment: Quick googling shows that DTrace can be used for the purpose. Also this might be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045575/how-to-trace-system-calls-of-a-program-in-mac-os-x

Comment: @SHAHAKASH got this error if I add sudo `Error: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

Comment: above error means when you add sudo then password prompt open and not given. for you can add nopassword to a specific path or give root access in sudoer file in ubantu.

Comment: in command line write command "which yarn" and give me the output.

Comment: @SHAHAKASH The behavior would be really wierd then if the issue was about permession. `EACCES` error has different code (13).

Comment: try this Runtime.getRuntime().exec(" /usr/local/bin/yarn -v");

Comment: @SHAHAKASH I got `Error: env: node: No such file or directory`

Comment: @maphongba008 take a look https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/issues/1118#issuecomment-393030063

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally found the answer, because the Process I start is different with the process of the terminal, so can't access /usr/local/bin, have to add `-l` to run the command as logged in user.
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash", "-l", "-c", cmd}, null, new File(f))`

Answer (score 1):

As `error` code 2 suggests you specified a path incorrectly. The error code corresponds to POSIX `ENOENT` and "No such file or directory" its `char * strerror(int errno)` representation.

To troubleshoot the problem by yourself you can read the manual page http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html

The relevant section is:

> ENOENT
>
> The file filename or a script or ELF interpreter does not 
>   exist, or a shared library needed for the file or interpreter 
>   cannot be found.

To see with which particula path your process is strarted run java witj `strace -f`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using an ANT script that at some point called javac task with a fork=true attribute. Inspired by maphongba008 answer I deleted that fork, and so I stopped getting this same error.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:

```
npm install -g yarn
```