# Browser Version Detection using Command line method using java

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox, command-line, microsoft-edge

I know the commands to get the browser version of Edge, Firefox and Chrome in **mac** using command line which is working properly on my system.
`Edge=/Applications/"Microsoft Edge.app"/Contents/MacOS/"Microsoft Edge" -version`
`FireFox=/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -v`
`Chrome=/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --version`

`Chrome1=/Applications/"Google Chrome.app"/Contents/MacOS/"Google Chrome" --version`

When I try with Firefox it successfully returns me the Firefox version.
but when I try for the Edge or the chrome it throws error in the java program.

Cannot run program "/Application/"Google" error=2 no such file or directory

I tried the escaping the query as `/Applications/\"Microsoft Edge.app\"/Contents/MacOS/\"Microsoft Edge\" -version`.I am printing the same before passing as a query and I am exactly getting the same query which works if I directly copy paste it on the terminal.

below is the code snippet

Am I missing something?

```
    String line;
            Process process;
            String msEdgeVersion = null;
    
            /*process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -v");*/
    
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(/Applications/"Microsoft Edge.app"/Contents/MacOS/"Microsoft Edge" -version);
    
            // process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("where notepad");
    
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (!StringUtils.isBlank(line)) {
                    msEdgeVersion = line;
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
            process.waitFor();
            process.destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the related api [Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String command)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)), you need to know that the parameter passed in is a **valid String**, so you need to pay attention to the format of the String parameter type.

**Edit**:

I reproduced your problem and got the same problem. After searching, I found the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54742540/java-caused-by-java-io-ioexception-error-2-no-such-file-or-directory). This is because the Process is different from the terminal process. You have to add `-l` to run the command as logged in user.

This is my test:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I have already tried this query as mentioned in the the question. It throws the same error.

Comment: Well, I only paid attention to your code and ignored what you described. I have modified the answer, I think this can help you.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I solved this problem using passing String array with few modifications in the command.                                                                                  
 String command =/Applications/Microsoft Edge.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Edge -version ;
    int lastSpaceIndex = command.lastIndexOf(" ");
    String[] commandArray = new String[]{command.substring(0, lastSpaceIndex),command.substring(lastSpaceIndex + 1)};                                                          I am passing commandArray to the exec() which worked for me.

Comment: I’m glad to hear that your issue has been resolved. If possible, you can post it as an answer, which may also help other members of the community.