# Android SDK on Alpine - adb No such file or directory

Tags: android, adb, alpine-linux

I'm trying to build an Alpine image containing the Android SDK - specifically, the `platform-tools` package.

My Dockerfile does the following:

1. Installs Java and sets `JAVA_HOME` (needed for Android).
2. Downloads the Android SDK tools from Google.
3. Unzips the package.
4. Sets `ANDROID_HOME`. Also sets `PATH` so the `sdkmanager` executable can be used.
5. Installs `platform-tools` using `sdkmanager`.
6. Adds `platform-tools` to `PATH`.

`platform-tools` contains an executable named `adb`, but for some reason it cannot be seen. Running `adb` returns:

```
bash: /android-sdk/platform-tools/adb: No such file or directory
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest

# Install bash and java
RUN apk update
RUN apk add bash openjdk8
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk
ENV PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"

# Download Android SDK and set PATH
RUN mkdir /android-sdk
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip && unzip *.zip -d /android-sdk && rm *.zip
ENV ANDROID_HOME="/android-sdk"
ENV PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin"

# Install platform-tools
RUN yes | sdkmanager "platform-tools"
ENV PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"
RUN adb version # throws error: adb not found
```

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571145/android-adb-not-found) but the problem should be fixed with platform-tools v24.0 and higher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alpine uses [musl libc](http://www.musl-libc.org/) instead of [glibc and friends](http://www.etalabs.net/compare_libcs.html), so certain software might run into issues depending on the depth of their libc requirements.

`adb` is compiled with `glibc`, so it won't be able to run in Alpine, which usually results in the error: `No such file or directory`.

You can verify that a file is compiled with `glibc` by running `file <path to file> | grep "interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"`.

Answer (score 2):

This may help, although the Gradle daemon randomly crashes for me on Alpine Linux when using the compatibility layer.

> gcompat is the go-to compatibility layer for Alpine users.
>
> **apk add gcompat**
>
> After that you run your binaries as normal.

Source: https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Running_glibc_programs

Answer (score -1):

You can install `android-tools` like so:

```
RUN apk add \
    android-tools \
    --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing
```

The key is to set the `--repository` as shown, as it's only in the edge testing repo.

I don't *think* it includes the whole SDK, so may need to download and unzip as well for other tools. I don't know if this will handle everything you want, but `adb` prints a help document at least.

Comment: Why is this answer ignored, its true you can add the 'android-tools' package ([source](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86/android-tools)) using `apk add android-tools`