# android imageView doesn't like my .png file

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am trying to load a .png file for for things in my app that do not have images.

I have my noImage.png in the res>drawable directory and try and set it with:

```
//set image
        ImageView im1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        if(e.largeLabel.equals("N/A")){
            //set image as png
            im1.setImageResource(R.drawable.noImage.png);
        }

        else{
            ImageDownloadTask imageD = new ImageDownloadTask(im1);
            imageD.execute(e.largeLabel);
        }
```

I get the error:

```
png cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

**Update:**

Based on some answers below I changed my code to this:

```
im1.setImageResource((Integer) R.drawable.noImage);
```

But I get this force close error:

```
06-24 21:05:58.922: E/AndroidRuntime(20741): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 21:05:58.922: E/AndroidRuntime(20741): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.beerportfoliopro/com.example.beerportfoliopro.BeerPage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-24 21:05:58.922: E/AndroidRuntime(20741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
06-24 21:05:58.922: E/AndroidRuntime(20741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
06-24 21:05:58.922: E/AndroidRuntime(20741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
06-24 21:05:58.922: E/AndroidRuntime(20741):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330)
06-24 21:05:58.922: E/AndroidRuntime(20741):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-24 21:05:58.922: E/AndroidRuntime(20741):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
06-24 21:05:58.922: E/AndroidRuntime(20741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
06-24 21:05:58.922: E/AndroidRuntime(20741):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 21:05:58.922: E/AndroidRuntime(20741):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-24 21:05:58.922: E/AndroidRuntime(20741):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
06-24 21:05:58.922: E/AndroidRuntime(20741):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
06-24 21:05:58.922: E/AndroidRuntime(20741):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-24 21:05:58.922: E/AndroidRuntime(20741): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-24 21:05:58.922: E/AndroidRuntime(20741):    at com.example.beerportfoliopro.BeerPage.onCreate(BeerPage.java:65)
06-24 21:05:58.922: E/AndroidRuntime(20741):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
06-24 21:05:58.922: E/AndroidRuntime(20741):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1102)
06-24 21:05:58.922: E/AndroidRuntime(20741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
06-24 21:05:58.922: E/AndroidRuntime(20741):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Why did you add the cast?

Comment: I get an error otherwise: The method setImageResource(int) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

Comment: wooooow. wait what? Object? what the hell have you done with the R file? R.drawable.(...) should return an integer. I think you have messed the imports.

Comment: @DiogoBento where can I find it so I can try and fix it? Eclipse suggested an edit to it earlier when I was trying to get my png to work...

Comment: look at the imports, the R file should be a reference to a class **inside** your project. not the android one neither anything else. You dont have to create an R file because it is generated automatically.

Comment: and btw, I truly recommend you to read some book about android..

Comment: I know eclipse edited the r file when I said yes to one of its suggestions, how can I undo it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2757131/2211156

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32300/discussion-between-mike-and-diogo-bento)

Comment: In Netbeans all I need to do is "clean and build" to regenerate the R file, I believe there is something similar in Eclipse, and you should really never manually modify R file

Comment: What's the code at the line giving the NPE (line 65)?

Answer (score 2):

My problem was the name of my image. I can not have uppercase letters in the res folder. I had to change the name from noImage.png to noimage.png and everyone was correct in that I do not use the .png when calling it in android.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, we cannot have any unique character for the resource naming, allowed: `lowercase & underscore` cmiiw

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the file extension when accessing resources. Use `R.drawable.noImage` instead.

Comment: Tried it but more errors, check my original question for update

Answer (score 0):

try without end : `im1.setImageResource(R.drawable.noImage);`

Comment: Then I get this error: The method setImageResource(int) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

Answer (score 0):

use this im1.setImageResource(R.drawable.noImage);

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
im1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.noImage));
```