# Android clean project deleted every R.java

Tags: android, xml

I updated my SDK version via eclipse, after that i did a project clean.
Now every R.java class of all my projects is gone.

Hints like "some .xmls are wrong" doesn'T work, because i didnt change anything in the .xmls..

Comment: Try to restart eclipse,if it doesn't work, re-start your PC.

Comment: Might try `Build > Rebuild Project` and see

Comment: If you have a compile error in an XML file the R.java will not be created. Fix all xml errors / compile errors, then do a `project > clean`

Comment: i did everything you suggested, but it didnt work..

Comment: Have you checked the casing of the filenames of the XML files?  For some reason, they have to be [a-z0-9] (lowercase alpha or numerals).  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating?rq=1) also has some of the most common solutions.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was go to `Project --> Build Project`

That worked once. The second time it didn't. The second time, I did this:

1. Create a brand new workspace.
2. `File --> Import...` and import the project that didn't have the `R.java` file.
3. It will generate the `R.java` file for you. So either use this workspace, or copy and paste this `R.java` file into your old workspace that didn't have it. Save everything and possibly restart Eclipse. It will work (even though it showed errors for a few minutes for me, they went away).

Answer (score 0):

If you have updated the adt to 22, then there is a common problem if you are using any external library.

In ADT 22 by default external libraries are unchecked.

`Please right click on project > properties > android > java build path > order and export > check Android private libraries`

Source: https://plus.google.com/photos/117122118961369445953/albums/5878509263473846433/5878509268379848162?authkey=CL3Frb-S_qj-fQ

Comment: thanks, but i solved the problem with uninstalling and reinstalling Android SDK Tools

Comment: OMG! You had to reinstall the SDK? That's cool that your problem is solved.. Sometimes eclipse is so unpredictable!!