# cannot regenerate r.java file in eclipse for android

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

I am new in android.
saw an android tutorial having downloadable program too. I downloaded it worked fine.
Taking help of that tutorial i tried to create one program for myself... but horrible things happen to me.
cant generate r.java
i searched lots on net but still having the problem.
i cleaned the project
rebuild
organized the order of exported jars

every one saying check xml file for errors
i checked all but eclipse does not showing any errors or warning on any of xml file.
got fully blank...

any help please...

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating/2757131#2757131

Comment: @SunilMishra i already saw that questions also follow it but as i told my r.java is not regenerating at all by cleaning and building or fixing project.. Also even at first time the r.java is not generating.. is version matter in this case???

Comment: There may be error in your XML files.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Project>Clean and selecting your project. This should generate the R.java file.

Or else you can right click on your project>Android Tools>Fix Project Properties.

Comment: i already mention that that's not working for me.... is version incompatible matter for this???