# Accidentally Deleted R.java

Tags: java, android

I was doing some work on my app when I accidentally deleted the file R.java in the gen folder. Is there any way to get it back? I need it because it is giving ever activity errors. I tried copying my data into another application and that didn't work. I also checked my recycle bin and there was no file and cleaned. Please help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Developing for Android in Eclipse: R.java not generating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating)

Comment: Usually the `R.java` is auto generated when you delete it, make sure the `xml` file has no error

Comment: Clean Project. Rebuild Project. Pray.

Answer (score 3):

Several ways to get out:

1. Simply modify(add a white space or so) in one of your resource files and save it, if the eclipse is enabled 'build automatically', the R.java will be re-generated again.
2. Go to project - clean project, clean your project and it will be re-generated when you run the project again

Comment: Please check if there is any error in your resource files. Are you using eclipse or any other IDE? Or just native command line build?

Answer (score 1):

It is automatically generated file

### Just clean and rebuild you project If there is no error{there must not any xml error which neither shown error nor let R.java build} then it will create your R.java file

again

Every Successful build just re-create new R.java file

Comment: there are no errors in the xml but i copied everything to a new app hoping the R.java would work there and it didnt work even with the new r.java

Comment: there must be some error in java or in manifest or in any xml

Answer (score 0):

R.java is auto generated when you delete it, make sure the xml file has no error . If this is also not solving your problem the **start doing your project from scratch no copy paste.**