# R.java not showing buttons, strings, or service

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

I updated several of my files but they do not appear as id #s in **R.java**. I tried updating my imports, I tried closing then opening Eclipse, saving, and closing/opening the Emulator, but it is not working to get **R.Java** to recognize the updates in the files. Of the items that are missing from R.java are 2 buttons (with 2 services) which would activate a toast when pressed, I will list the files below, each one. I run the emulator (Virtual, Nexus API 17) and it shows an old version of my app that has no buttons, only text that says "Hello World". Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** I tried to clean my project (thinking that if the **R.java** got regenerated, then it might update itself), but it just made the **R.java** disappear, and created an error in the main folder, HelloWorld in the Package Explorer. Oddly enough, there were no other errors in the entire series of files that I edited. No yellow warnings, nothing. Plus I never edited the R.java file (I know it's a no-no). So then after I tried to run my project anyway, this error posted in the LogCat below.

I found this in the LogCat:

> 01-03 06:54:13.977: E/ThrottleService(300): problem during
>   onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all:
>   open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

**Here are my files:**

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       }

       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
          return true;
       }

       // Method to start the service
       public void startService(View view) {
          startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
       }

       // Method to stop the service
       public void stopService(View view) {
          stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
       }

}
```

**MyService.java**

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {
   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
      return null;
   }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
      Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return START_STICKY;
   }
   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <Button android:id="@+id/btnStartService"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/start_service"
   android:onClick="startService"/>

   <Button android:id="@+id/btnStopService"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/stop_service"
   android:onClick="stopService" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">HelloWorld</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
    <string name="start_service">Start Service</string>
    <string name="stop_service">Stop Service</string>

</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.helloworld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

  <application
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
           android:name=".MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <service android:name=".MyService" />
   </application>
</manifest>
```

and finally, the **R.java** (which ignores many strings and other names)

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */

package com.example.helloworld;

public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class dimen {
        /**  Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. 

         Customize dimensions originally defined in res/values/dimens.xml (such as
         screen margins) for sw720dp devices (e.g. 10" tablets) in landscape here.

         */
        public static final int activity_horizontal_margin=0x7f040000;
        public static final int activity_vertical_margin=0x7f040001;
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;
    }
    public static final class id {
        public static final int action_settings=0x7f080000;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int activity_main=0x7f030000;
    }
    public static final class menu {
        public static final int main=0x7f070000;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int action_settings=0x7f050001;
        public static final int app_name=0x7f050000;
        public static final int hello_world=0x7f050002;
    }
    public static final class style {
        /** 
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.


            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.


        Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.

 API 11 theme customizations can go here. 

        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.

 API 14 theme customizations can go here. 
         */
        public static final int AppBaseTheme=0x7f060000;
        /**  Application theme. 
 All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. 
         */
        public static final int AppTheme=0x7f060001;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors in res folder in your project ? If there are any errors in res, R.java never generate again.

Comment: @Noni Azure Just uninstall your application from the emulator and try to run the application again.

Comment: Prince, no there are no errors in my res/ folder 
@shiju B, i tried to clean it, but then got errors since R.java did not regenerate. then i //commented out all the R.java calls, then cleaned again, then a red X box shows up on my HelloWorld folder in my package explorer (and R.java did not regenerate a 2nd time), but i am looking everywhere and i see no errors anywhere in other files, not even yellow warnings. strange.

Comment: GrlsHu, sorry i am still a beginner, how do i uninstall the emulator?

Comment: Never manually update R.java.

Comment: @NoniAzure Have a look : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2757131/1405983

Comment: Checkout my updated answer to uninstall the application. @NoniAzure

Comment: @GrIsHu buddy user facing error in eclipse project. After uninstalling application from emulator errors resolved ?

Comment: @Prince Check out user's updated answer. He is facing another issue.

Comment: @NoniAzure Have you added any library into your project ?

Comment: GrlsHu, i have not added a library that i know of, but just copied code from a book. they were trying to teach us how to use Services.

Comment: Okey! so using uninstalling application from emulator, R.java generate again ?

Comment: here is the original tutorial (just one page) and i copied what they suggested in the files they suggested.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm

Comment: @GrIsHu I already read entire question from first and after edited. You answer still not seems right. User have issue in building project/ she menually updated R.java / Forgot add library projects in build path. I think TalhaQ is right. I also checked by creating eclipse project. There are no errors in my project.

Comment: @Prince, is there a way to find if i have an incompatible library? i checked the Android Private Libraries in my package explorer, but there are no red errors over any of them. technically though, i do not recall installing any libraries.

Comment: @NoniAzure Did you check by downloading project which TalhaQ given in answer ?

Comment: @Prince, yes his file worked! but i must find out why before i check his option as the answer, because the answer will not be useful for anyone else, unless i can explain why it worked. a very strange bug though, i don't know why it was saying there was an error, when there were no visible errors in any of the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After great help from everyone, the final solution was to begin a new project, then copy/paste each important file back into it, including updating the **AndroidManifest.xml** file. However, the order of operations was very important. The rebuild did not work if I copy and pasted the **MainActivity.java** file first, rebuilding that way gave me that odd HelloWorld folder error with no other errors in all my other files. So I thought maybe rebuilding in a certain order would work, and it did.

I had to do the rebuild in this order:

- **strings.xml**
- **activity_main.xml**
- **MyService.java**
- update the **AndroidManifest.xml** (with the addition of the **MyService.java** in `<service>` tags)
- then finally the **MainActivity.java**

I then updated all imports and saved everything, and low and behold, **R.java** was updated with the right ids for all of my strings and other name ids.

So while I still don't understand why I had a red error on my HelloWorld project folder in Package Explorer (that did not show a single error or warning anywhere else in any of my edited files), it looks like rebuilding the file by cutting and pasting in a new project, in a careful order, ended up updating the **R.java** so that I could run successfully in the emulator.

Special thanks to @TalhaQ for suggesting my files were okay and to reuse the code. Although I know I did not edit the **R.java** file at all, it's still a mystery why it never updated like it should have. Might have had something to do with the order of operations in the original file, since the order of operations mattered a lot in the rebuild.

Comment: Congratulations Noni. Happy codding.

Answer (score 3):

You code is perfectly fine.I think you might have damaged R.java and put something by your self.I have compiled your code it works fine.You can even download from this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wozwhgd3kbi1ixe/SampleService.rar).

Comment: TalhaQ, i imported your SampleService folder into Eclipse, then run it, and wow that worked! how did you do that? create a new project, then copy/paste the code from all those files, then save it so that the R.java would update? I am very curious how this got to work now! Thanks so much!

Comment: Always Welcome.Yes i just copy and paste your code in new project and run it.FYI never mess with the R.java. :)

Comment: Oh TalhaQ, now I tried to do this, but it is doing the same thing as before. i tried to copy and paste the MainActivity.java, the strings.xml, the MyService.java, and AndroidManifest.xml, but it is giving the same error over the HelloWorld folder.

Also, i looked into your MyService file, and a `Log.d("Service Started","Service Started");` and 'Log.d("Service Destroyed","Service Destroyed");' was added. did you manually do this? did you manually change anything in the files? because that is very important to include.

Comment: thanks again TalhaQ, your answer was not 100% correct, so i compiled everything into one answer, with a detailed explanation of what worked in the end. but yours was very helpful, much appreciation!

Comment: Yes i added them to ensure that service started/destroyed.Are you replacing the code in your current project??I advice you to create a new project and do all the same things as you mentioned above :)

Comment: how my answer wasn't correct? are you find any errors in my code? :P

Comment: Oh no, it was correct TalhaQ! :D but i did not alter my R.java, so I didn't want people to think that part of what you said was true. plus i made a new discovery that the order of copy/pasting (or just creating the files) was important, so i thought i should combine into a more full answer.

Comment: Also TalhaQ, i did copy the code as it was originally, so i left out any additions you made, and it worked. it really must have been the order of operations that prevented R.java from updating properly.

Answer (score -1):

As you have stated in your question `it shows an old version of my app that has no buttons, only text that says "Hello World".`

Just try to uninstall the old application from your emulator and try to run the project.

**Go to Settings>ApplicationManager> select your application> Uninstall**

Comment: This is reason why R.java not generated ?

Comment: @Prince Just wait before i update my answer. I know its not reason.

Comment: thanks GrlsHu, i don't see Settings in my ADT menu, I'm using Android Developer Tools

Build: v22.3.0-887826

I could go to the Virtual Device Manager to delete the emulator, should i try that?

Comment: Check out in your emulator the Settings icon will be there.

Comment: thanks GrlsHu, i checked the icons in the Emulator, i found Dev Settings only, and did not see an uninstall option. i also looked in the upper file menu, but that is very limited, only has an About, a Quit, and a Minimize (Window).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion GrlsHu, what happened was the R.java was not updating, then i tried to clean it, then R.java disappeared and showed an odd error, and I think that you came in at the beginning before my R.java disappeared, so it evolved into an R.java issue at a point in the process. i will consider this answer another time though!