# R Missing In Gen Folder In Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

http://puu.sh/69sfM ~ Screenshot

I do not have a R file in my gen folder. I have gone through many different threads and none of the presented solutions have worked. I have even tried copying and pasting the R.Java file from a different project into this gen folder but when I clean & rebuild it automatically deletes the file.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: check all xml file and Manifest file, its might have an error, if don't clean your project and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying and pasting R from another project is WRONG.
R must be generated, always.

If it doesn't generate, some of your xml files contain errors (even small ones).
For instance, it can be a >> (double closing of a tag) or a wrong attribute name.
Look in EVERY xml file in your project, line by line, and you'll find the error.

Once I had this issue because of an error in strings.xml.

Comment: Okay. But I've looked through every xml file and nothing is wrong. My project was working fine before I changed my background then an error  occurred in my main xml. R errors popped up and even after I fixed my xml errors the R errors were not resolved.

Comment: Well, what is your background? an xml drawable or an image? Do you have a previous copy of main.xml, so that you can try if the old version works (also make a copy of the new one, to compare them)?

Comment: I actually tried changing the background back to white to see if the issue would resolve itself but it didn't work. And I added the image as an xml drawable.

Comment: Did you double check every line, for the smallest error? Sometimes errors are so good in hiding, you know... also check your menu.xml, your preferences.xml, EVERY xml you have in your project - you never know where the error hides

Comment: Okay, is it possible that they will not show as errors sometimes?

Comment: Yes, it can happen that **sometimes the errors aren't marked**

Comment: It turns out that I had added an image into my drawables that had an uppercase letter haha. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Wonderful that you killed the bug! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Clean your project and run it.

`Project`---> `Clean` then run

see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating) it gives perfect solution for you..

Comment: change the build target version and clean the project, after completing that change that build version to previous.

it works for me.