# Can't Find Blank Activity in Eclipse New android Application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ubuntu-13.10

Hi all my problem is I was setting the eclipse environment for Ubuntu 13.10 with eclipse, SDK and JDK 7.

Normally when I create New->Android Application Project and going through this process I supposed to see:

1. Blank Activity
2. FullScreen Activity
3. Master/Detail Flow

**Problem:**

First option (1- Blank Activity) don't show up and I don't know why.
I hope anyone can help in this problem or tell me how to create an activity in an empty project.

**I've tried:**

I tried to install another copy of eclipse and link it with the SDK but that didn't work also.

Comment: do you see the options for the other templates? ... for your Question, you can simply create a new Class which is a subclass of activity; overwrite constructor an onCreate() but DONT FORGET to make an entry in the AndroidManifest

Comment: I created a new empty  and I added a java class as activity  but it kept give me error in R.java which is auto generated but to be honst i didn't change anything in the ndroidManifest can you tell me what i have to edit in it ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

ok you must extend you AndroidManifest.xml file, the reply function is too small for a full reply, so i'll post this solution :-~

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <!-- Main (starter) Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="cn.brandhook.apps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- blank (new created) Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="cn.brandhook.apps.NewBlankActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_new_blank_activity"
        android:parentActivityName="MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="MainActivity" />
    </activity>   

</application>
```

having problems with R.Java not created/reCreated you should check [Developing for Android in Eclipse: R.java not regenerating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating)

i guess this won't help you much, but it was supposed to be a mere reply (comment)

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstalled Everything and it worked very well.
Any way now the official Version for Android Development is Android Studio.