# Cleaned the project and r.java is not generated

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, r.java-file

I have a project i used that worked fine, then i replaced a java file(class) with file from  some other java project(had extra code in it), and also the strings.xml and some of the layouts.
and now this class dont recognise some of the new xml id's, even though i double-checked and everything seemed ok and hit "save" on each of the files. I tried to clean the project and it made the R.java file disappear for good.
I checked the answers in:

> [Developing for Android in Eclipse: R.java not regenerating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating)

But nothing helped me.

The XML files have no errors, and i didnt changed the manifest file. 
Only replaced a .java file and the layouts.
What else can be the problem? It is the second time it happens to me while trying to "import" others files to my project.

Comment: Make sure that all your resource files don't have upper case letters in their names.

Comment: Check lint for errors.

Answer (score 0):

restart, clean and rebuild your application  in android studio or java application help. If you are using android studio then, You can also try to sync project files with gradle file.

should be under tools --> android --> sync project files with gradle file in your android studio.

Comment: Im using Eclipse. and the automatic build is checked

Answer (score 0):

try clean your eclipse using terminal. cd to your eclipse directory. Mine like this

```
cd /Applications/eclipse_juno/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS
```

then clean

```
./eclipse -clean
```

done