# is importing R.java correct?

Tags: android, import, r.java-file

I know this question might have been asked a thousand times on StackOverflow, but I have a precise question : When I have the problem of "R cannot be resolved to a variable", should I import the R of the package ? I know that eclipse suggests it and doing it solves the problem but is that correct to have the import of R in the class ?

Comment: `R cannot be resolved to a variable` is typically shown when R is deleted, due to som eerror/s in some xml file/s (not only layouts) AND/OR invalid characters in file names, such as UPPER CASE letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. All of your resource ids are compiled into R.java. If you do not import `com.mypackage.R` then any references such as `R.id.textview` will not resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you don't need to import R.java. As @Vyger said, most of the time when Eclipse suggests you to import R.java there is something wrong with your R.java... Try to delete and recreate it (See [Developing for Android in Eclipse: R.java not regenerating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating)).

This will solve the problem most of the time... If this doesn't work, just import it. It won't harm your application.