# Using Radio Button: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, xml, radio-button

I have the following source code and i can not open my .xml file to edit the widgets. 
This error appeared from nothing. Could somebody help me?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:background="#FFFFFF">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cpf"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/common_signin_btn_light_text_focused"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/cpf" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtCpf"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cpf"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textColor="@color/abc_search_url_text_normal" >
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/acontecimento"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtCpf"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/common_signin_btn_light_text_focused"
    android:text="@string/acontecimento" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtAcontecimento"
    android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/acontecimento"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:maxLength="50"
    android:textColor="@color/abc_search_url_text_normal" >
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/evento"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtAcontecimento"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/common_signin_btn_light_text_focused"
    android:text="@string/selecioneEvento" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/evento"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_group1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_alerta"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@color/abc_search_url_text_normal"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/alerta"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_arvore"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/arvore"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_chuva"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/chuva"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_raio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/raio"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_temperatura"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/temperatura"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_vento"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/vento"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeGroup"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btRegistrar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="@string/registrarEventoCadastro"
        android:textColor="@color/common_signin_btn_text_light" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btVoltar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/voltar"
        android:textColor="@color/common_signin_btn_text_light" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The error log:

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- RadioButton (Change to android.widget.RadioButton, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:textAppearance="@color/abc_search_url_text_normal"
```

try to remove that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe your R class is not generated successfully.

Check [R class generating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating)

Else check the imports in your Activity. Has to be `com.example.yourapp.R` (replace `com.example.yourappp` with your tag.

Comment: Well, i did that before, and still not working either, but uDevel found the problem: it was android:textAppearance="@color/abc_search_url_text_normal"