# R.java won't generate, and there are no errors in resource files

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, r.java-file

After cleaning my project, my R.java file hasn't generated.

I've tried the following:

1. Update eclipse. But my version is already up to date.
2. Try cleaning the project again.
3. Look for errors in my drawable XML files and layout files. I found none.
4. Look through my Activity classes for errors; there were none except for the `R.java` references.

What else can I try?

I'm considering copy-pasting all of my classes, resources and manifest into a new project, but I'm wondering if there's anything else I can do.

Comment: maybe there will be some problem in xml file

Comment: Check not only drawables and layouts... maybe strings, dimens, styles, ... Check for file names containing Upper Case letters or hyphens, too.

Comment: I've looked through everything. And there aren't any of those error symbols that eclipse displays next to a file, except for on files that mention `R.java` of course.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating see thsi

Comment: What is valid xml may not be valid Android xml. What I mean is that what won't work for android may not be marked as an error in your IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the strangest thing happened. I was randomly trying multiple things to get `R.java` back, and ended up right clicking ANOTHER project in my workspace (appcompat_v7, which I think was automatically generated), clicking properties, clicking `Java Build Path`, and checking some of the entries.

I don't understand why this worked, but it did. If anyone could pitch in a reason though, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import same project in another work space and then clean build it ,it has done trick for me might b helpfull to you