# Android R.java not generating with following error

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

My R.java don't want to generate with following error :

```
[2014-06-02 12:05:33 - test] Using default Build Tools revision 19.1.0
[2014-06-02 12:05:33 - test] Refreshing resource folders.
[2014-06-02 12:05:33 - test] Using default Build Tools revision 19.1.0
[2014-06-02 12:05:33 - test] Starting incremental Pre Compiler: Checking resource changes.
[2014-06-02 12:05:33 - test] Preparing generated java files for update/creation.
[2014-06-02 12:05:33 - test] /home/erwan/.android-sdks/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt package -m -v -J /home/erwan/workspace/test/gen -M /home/erwan/workspace/test/AndroidManifest.xml -S /home/erwan/workspace/test/res -I /home/erwan/.android-sdks/platforms/android-19/android.jar 
[2014-06-02 12:05:33 - test] /home/erwan/.android-sdks/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2014-06-02 12:05:33 - test] /home/erwan/.android-sdks/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2014-06-02 12:05:33 - test] 'aapt' error. Pre Compiler Build aborted.
[2014-06-02 12:05:34 - test] Removing generated java classes.
[2014-06-02 12:05:34 - test] Using default Build Tools revision 19.1.0
[2014-06-02 12:05:34 - test] Refreshing resource folders.
[2014-06-02 12:05:34 - test] Using default Build Tools revision 19.1.0
[2014-06-02 12:05:34 - test] Starting full Pre Compiler.
[2014-06-02 12:05:34 - test] Removing generated java classes.
[2014-06-02 12:05:34 - test] Generating BuildConfig.java...
[2014-06-02 12:05:34 - test] Preparing generated java files for update/creation.
[2014-06-02 12:05:34 - test] /home/erwan/.android-sdks/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt package -m -v -J /home/erwan/workspace/test/gen -M /home/erwan/workspace/test/AndroidManifest.xml -S /home/erwan/workspace/test/res -I /home/erwan/.android-sdks/platforms/android-19/android.jar 
[2014-06-02 12:05:34 - test] /home/erwan/.android-sdks/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2014-06-02 12:05:34 - test] /home/erwan/.android-sdks/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2014-06-02 12:05:34 - test] 'aapt' error. Pre Compiler Build aborted.
[2014-06-02 12:05:35 - test] Using default Build Tools revision 19.1.0
[2014-06-02 12:05:35 - test] Refreshing resource folders.
[2014-06-02 12:05:35 - test] Starting full Package build.
[2014-06-02 12:05:35 - test] Using default Build Tools revision 19.1.0
```

Project have been cleaned and fixed, still no R.java. I have generated a new project, same problem. I have reinstalled libstdc++ with no change.

Comment: `libstdc++` is this coming as a .jar? make sure it is in your build path

Comment: what is the IDE you used?

Comment: Better to check this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling all Android SDK component solved the problem.

- Removed all Eclipse Android add-on
- Removed SDK and all its component
- Reinstalling the Android SDK
- Reinstalling Eclipse Android add-on
- Reinstalling all SDK component
- Clean all project
- `R.java` is back.

Answer (score 1):

There are three things you have to check.

1.if xml file name is uppercase, R.java error will occur.
change the name to lowercase.

2.if resource file(etc. image,sound) is uppercase, R.java error will occur.
change the name to lowercase.

then project->clean

3.check if Android SDK Build-tools is installed in SDK Manager.

If the error is not resolved, upgrade android sdk version.

Comment: 1,2 and 3 Done, no change

Comment: right click project and select Properties -> java BuildPath -> order and export Tab. select android version of project and move to the top