# eclipse adt stuck at invoking android pre compiler

Tags: android, preprocessor, adt, eclipse-adt

i have only the project google-play-services-lib on my eclipse android workspace. When i build automatically the projects on workspace, the building process goes to 75% and it loads infinitely. It is stuck on the "invoking android pre compiler" task. Any ideas how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need check the all the lib which you attached with your project. After you update android sdk after that you need to restart eclipse then try and also clean your project.

Comment: what sdk? android sdk tools using the android sdk manager? Cleaning my project is getting me stuck at invoking android pre compiler too

Comment: I use sdk because once you update you android environment then all the new andorid api and there os images is save in your sdk dir. May you please share screen shot what exactly issue at 75 % process.

Comment: this problem is happening only on my brother's computer. My eclipse adt does not have the same issue and my android sdk manager still has some updates for me that i didn´t do. Does the updates really have something to do with it?

Comment: yeah after update you need to restart the eclipse and Is adt path is available in environment?

Comment: here is a screenshot of the problem: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10204603571070640&set=pb.1275445765.-2207520000.1412087459.&type=3&theater

Comment: yeah, the adt path is correct on the environment variables

Comment: there's a common bug on the problems tag that is "R cannot be resolved". But isn´t the solution for this problem cleaning the project? How can i clean the project if eclipse stucks at cleaning the project? When i try to clean my project, it gets stuck on invoking pre compiler too

Comment: r java is not created when there is some files in drawable folder with irregular format. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating follow this discussion

Comment: it is now getting stuck at "invoking android package builder". I only have the "google-play-services-lib" project on my workspace. It is stuck at 100%. The project has no errors on the error log or the problem tag