# Cleaning my project in Eclipse caused errors

Tags: android, eclipse

So I've been working on projects for my class and I had a small error in an extra instance I was calling. I hit clean to see if it would clear it out and instead it created errors on all of my buttons and all of my toasts. It now says they all cannot be resolved or are not fields. They were all working fine until I had hit clean as I had tested everything right before doing so. Has anyone else had this occur?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Developing for Android in Eclipse: R.java not generating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating)

Comment: lol..your eclipse is horny..lolol-(rolling and cackling..).. jux do this clean once and build manually,dont let eclispe build automatically it sometimes builds immaturely, then restart.. it will work. and lastly if you hava additional libraries re-check its imports

Answer (score -1):

I know it sounds weird, but this occurs when there is an error in one of the .XML layouts, no matter Eclipse is not detecting it. Please check any recent changes in XMLs and clean again.