# Eclipse: R not found after updating Android ADT to revision 23.0.5

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I have updated Eclipse ADT from revision 22 to 23.0.5 but after updating it is giving an error of R not found. I have restarted the eclipse couple of time but problem persists. What could be the issue?
See my SDK status as attached in picture below.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any sort of errors in your XMLs? (Values files perhaps)

Comment: Did you remember to `Help/Check for updates`, after upgrading the SDK?

Comment: Is it a windows machine? Can you see whats the error you are getting in problems view?

Comment: There is not any error in xml file, yes it did help/check for updates but it said no new updates available after 23 revision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have Android SDK Build-tools installed on your machine. 
Just install the Android SDK Build-tools version 19.1 and this should resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

### Possible reasons for your error

1. There is some errors in xml
2. You might be using a image or a resource name that does not exists
3. As far as i know updating ADT will not cause this error

***Double check on above things*** because if resources are referenced correctly `R.java` will automatically be generated !

---

### Also install this update

[image]

---

### Still if you are not able to resolve check these ways to do it below

I am quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15761439/1083093) from another StackOverflow Question

- Make sure that anything the `R.` links to is not broken. **Fix all errors in your XML files**. If anything in the ADKs are broken, `R` will not regenerate.
- If you somehow hit something and created `import android.R` in your activity, **remove it**.
- Run **Project -> Clean**. This will delete and regenerate R and BuildConfig.
- Make sure **Project -> Build Automatically** is ticked. If not, build it manually via `Menu -> Project -> Build Project` .
- **Wait** a few seconds for the errors to disappear.
- If it doesn't work, delete everything inside the /gen/ folder
- If it still doesn't work, try **right-clicking your project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties**.
- Check your ***.properties** files (in the root folder of your app folder) and make sure that the links in there are not broken.
- Right-click your **project > properties > Android**. Look at the Project Build Target and Library sections on the right side of the page. Your Build Target should match the target in your AndroidManifest.xml. So if it's set to target 17 in AndroidManifest, make sure that the Target Name is Android 4.2. If your Library has an X under the reference, remove and re-add the library until there's a green tick. This might happen if you've moved a few files and folders around.

#### What to do if R doesn't regenerate

This usually happens when you have a broken xml file.

- Check errors inside your XML files, mainly within the /res/ folder
- Common places are /layout/ and /values/ especially if you've changed one of them recently
- Check `AndroidManifest.xml`, I find that often I change a string, and forget to change the string name from `AndroidManifest.xml`.
- Check that `Android SDK Build-tools` is installed. **Window->Android SDK Manager->Tools->Android SDK Build-tools**
- Make sure when you update the `Android SDK Tools`, you also update the `Android SDK Platform-tools` and `Android ADK Build-tools`.  Build fails silently if they don't match.
- If you can't find the issue, **right click /gen/ -> Restore from local history... -> tick R.java -> click Restore**. Even if it doesn't solve the problem, but it will clear out the extra errors to make the problem easier to find.

---

### *Last but not least clean and run every-time u check for above possible ways*

Comment: I have created new Test project for testing this error, but still R not found error exist

Comment: Thanks Devrath for your reply, I was not having build tools.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning your project normally fixes this.

Click 'Project' -> 'Clean...' Select your project from the list and hit 'OK'

Comment: Cleaned couple of times but still problem persists

Answer (score 0):

1. check your sdk folder
   (add-ons folder ~ tools folder - about 9 ~ 11 folders)

1.2 if some folder was deleted, download ADT(in google website) and copy & paste sdk folder.

2. sdk folder was good, check android target api is exist(project right click - properties...)