# Cannot create android project compile with older API (like API 17)

Tags: android, eclipse

Why I can only create android project that compile with API 21 or API 22? other than this 2, all will have error with `R cannot be resolved`, and if I import `android.R`, it will give me another error which is `activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field`. I search for solution from Google but all doesn't work for me. Help me please.
[image: R cannot be resolved to a variable]

and here is the error if I import `android.R`
[image: activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field]

and if I change to `avtivity_list_item` there still have error.

Comment: Firstly, never import android.R especially as it has no relevance to your own R.java class. Secondly, for your firat (actual) error about "R cannot be resolved to a variable" - it will be because your R.java file is not being auto-generated - you can check your project's /gen folder to confirm this. The usual reason R.java isn't generated is there is a fatal exception at build time - check the Console, it should give further information. Also, try to Clean and Rebuild your project which can sometimes fix problems with R.java not being auto-generated.

Comment: Are you changing the build tools version or the target version? Have you installed the right build tools in the SDK manager?

Comment: @Squonk yes, the R.java file is not generated. I can't find it in the gen folder, so how?

Comment: @AhYong : As I said in my comment - check the Console output when you attempt to build - it should give more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

**Well for the first error:**
check your SDK Manager to see if you have the the *4.2.2(API 17)* installed.

**And for the second:**
I had this problem sometime ago, all you have to do is clean your project and build it again as this answer suggests [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating), see if that helps.