# R Java cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I was working in a Android project and I imported it to another laptop to continue my work, but then I got this error in the project:

```
Description : R cannot be resolved to a variable
Resource : AccueilFragment.java
Path : /AppV1/src/com/example/appv1 
Type : Java Problem
```

The folder gen(Generated Java Files) contain just the package com.example.appv1--->BuildConfig.java and there is not the file R.java

Comment: Clean and build your project

Comment: Here are some detailed answers to this error:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error

Comment: Clean and Re-Build your Project.
If it still generates no R, you may have some Errors. Errors could be in every Folder (style, values, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same problem
Try this:

Go to Properties->Java Build Path,
Now Select "Order and Export" Tab,
Unchecked the JAR file (like v4 or v7) and then clean the project

I think this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check drawable folders may have png images with not valid names or resources
2. Clean the project select project->Menu->project->clean selected project
3. Create a new workspace and add the backup copy of your project at newly one