# R.java does not contain class id

Tags: android

[the line `username =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);` is generating error `editText1 cannot be resolved or it is not a field`.how to solve this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8liy.png)

Comment: I believe this is auto generated code.

Answer (score 2):

Android **R.java** is an `auto-generated file by aapt` (Android Asset Packaging Tool) that contains resource IDs for all the resources of `res/ directory`.

*Clean-Rebuild-Remove* `gen` Folder-Restart

- If you somehow hit something and created `import android.R` in your activity, **remove it**.
- Run **Project -> Clean**. This will delete and regenerate R and BuildConfig.
- Make sure **Project -> Build Automatically** is ticked. If not, build it manually via `Menu -> Project -> Build Project` .

> [Developing for Android in Eclipse: R.java not regenerating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-regenerating)

Answer (score 1):

`R.java` is auto generated code. Please delete your `gen` (in eclipse) folder and try re-build the app.

Comment: i watched tutorials and in those tutorials R.java file was not as long as my eclipse generates.

Comment: What are the tutorials ? R.java file keep resource related information.  once the resouces changes it will re-generate with changes. There are two kind of R files . Android has a inbuilt R file for their ids.