# Strange case where R file is not generated

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

I have faced case where R file not generated automatically. However, this time is quite weird.

I have checked under `res` folder, there is no wrong in naming convention and there is no error under that folder.

I build the project min 9 and targetSDKVersion 21, and build target 21 too and I have updated Eclipse and also Android SDK Tools. What else do I need to check? I can't find the cause of error at all.

Comment: SWITCH TO ANDROID STUDIO .

Comment: Wow your first name is IntelliJ :D Btw I can't switch it since this is my company project.

Comment: Deleting the build folders manually, clean and rebuild doesn't worked?

Comment: Nope, did it several times

Comment: @Rendy the error is encouraging you to try Android Studio listen to it dude ;)

Comment: any wrong resource? It just needs a little mistake for example in Your xml layouts and then the R file will not be generated.....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I think so .

Comment: What makes me confused is, my other colleague can compile and run the code, while i am not. I also want to switch to AS, as my own projects always runs in AS without this frustating problem.

Comment: @Rendy Be cool , Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-regenerating

Comment: if the problem is R file not recognized in class, then manually import R file => import <your_package_name>[dot]R => then clean/refresh build

Comment: @Rendy switch to different workspace and import same project then check.

Comment: I have solved it guys anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced such problems many times.

Try below ways and you may be lucky to fix your issue:

Change the API Level to some other API Level. Then Apply. Again revert back to original API Level. By Right Click on the Project -> Properties -> Android.

or

Clean the Project.

or

Restart Eclipse.

Hope it will get fixed and Enjoy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that all your reference library are in the same workspace folder.
2. Clean and Refresh project at least 3 times :).
3. If nothing works, recreate the entire workspace...creating new workspace and import your project to this new workspace or delete .metadata folder of your workspace and restart Eclipse, import your projects again.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Well finally I get rid of it after 6 hours. I downloaded new release of Eclipse (Mars), re-clone my project, install ADT on new Eclipse and it works now. Previously I used Luna release 2.

Comment: Happy to hear .Move ahead .