# Missing R.java during coding

Tags: android, r.java-file

I was working on my project when suddenly the R.java disappeared and the entire project is broken now as the R is missing. I tried rebuilding it again but it's not working ......... any solutions, please?

Error messages:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
C:\Users\devha\AndroidStudioProjects\SystemApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
Error:(13, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay').
C:\Users\devha\AndroidStudioProjects\SystemApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main2.xml
Error:(13, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay').
Error:(20, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'popupTheme' with value '@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay').
C:\Users\devha\AndroidStudioProjects\SystemApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main3.xml
Error:(12, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay').
C:\Users\devha\AndroidStudioProjects\SystemApp\app\src\main\res\layout\content_main2.xml
Error:(83, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/sign_out').
C:\Users\devha\AndroidStudioProjects\SystemApp\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\activity_main.xml
Error:(13, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay').
C:\Users\devha\AndroidStudioProjects\SystemApp\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\activity_main2.xml
Error:(13, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay').
Error:(20, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'popupTheme' with value '@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay').
C:\Users\devha\AndroidStudioProjects\SystemApp\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\activity_main3.xml
Error:(12, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay').
C:\Users\devha\AndroidStudioProjects\SystemApp\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\content_main2.xml
Error:(83, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/sign_out').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 11.348 secs
Information:11 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Developing for Android in Eclipse: R.java not regenerating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-regenerating)

Comment: Seems any problem woth styles xml and theme.

Comment: just restart android studio or clean your project and rebuild it! thts it

Comment: can you upload your activity_main.xml and style.xml too

Answer (score 0):

1. Check all Layout file and fix error if any.
2. Delete build folder of project and app.
3. Then clean your project and rebuild it.

It will fix your problem. :)

Comment: wat does R.java file has to do with build folder?, #1 and #3 will make the things work

Comment: @MohammedAtif R.java and related compiled .class files are in the build folder. I think that deleting it will make Android Studio rebuild the entire thing.

Comment: for that run -> clean project and then run -> rebuild project, you dont need to manually delete any of them until and unless seriously required

Comment: R.java is auto generated file. Once I had similar problem I just deleted build folder and and it worked.