# R.java id name missing

Tags: android, file

in my android studio project R.java file missing id name

```
 public static final class id 
     {
        public static final int                  =0x7f0c00a2;
        public static final int Enter_manually_gone=0x7f0c015e;
        public static final int Regenerate_layout_gone=0x7f0c0160;
        public static final int aboutTV=0x7f0c00e0;
        public static final int aboutusTV=0x7f0c007a;
     }
```

I am tried all thing, clean project, rebuild project
but my issue not resolve 
please help me out

Comment: too old question. Its auto generate class .`Clean-Rebuild` your IDE

Comment: Its not working for me. i have done all these thing

Comment: see below answer and comment

Comment: plz try this solution 

regenerate R: File->Settings->Compiler
then UNCHECK "Use in-process build"
clear project
Rebuild Project

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have any errors **under your Problems tab in Eclipse**. Try to use Fix Project Properties under Android Tools when your right click on your project.

If that doesn't fix your problem, try modifying your AndroidManifest.xml (just add a space and save). I've heard that will force the R.java to rebuild.

- except for errors that says R cannot be resolved to a variable - these errors will go away once you correct other errors and force R.java to rebuild.

from: [Developing for Android in Eclipse: R.java not regenerating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-regenerating)

Comment: I already suggest him

Comment: he using android studio

Comment: Did you try to Invalidate Caches / Restart option from File Menu ?

Comment: Add this on comment section

Comment: yeah am already try Invalidate Caches / Restart  but not working for me

Comment: even i hard deleted this file but still facing same issue

Comment: This is why you always have to upload your project to git :(