# Why do I always get R error in android 3.1.2?

Tags: java, android

This is the error message:

> AAPT2 error: check logs for details

before the above error, I have cleaned up the project from build.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you `check logs for details`?  Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-regenerating

Comment: It maybe about your xml files. Can you tell the details of error in log?

Answer (score 1):

Try re-importing the "R" file and re-building the project.