# R.java missing, closed emulator at construction

Tags: android, emulation, r.java-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to regenerate R class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041083/how-to-regenerate-r-class)

I didn't know so yes i did close the emulator at the construction time and my  R.java is gone, how do fix it? i researched and they said it could be some Capital Letter but everything in my project is lowercased so i dont know what to do.

I did clean my project more then 10 times and nothing.

I also did import all R in every file and cleaned it but no result.

**EDIT**

The error appeared when i changed the Project version from 4.1 to 2.2 so I changed back to 4.1 and the R.java got back, but why does it desappear when is 2.2? because I need it to be 2.2

Comment: did you try restarting eclipse?

Comment: Yes. i did restart and cleaned loads of time

Comment: @Sam NOTHING from that link is helping me.

Comment: I'm sorry the link didn't help, but your question is a little vague so I cannot give you concrete advice. But this is a common problem, did you also read [Developing for Android in Eclipse: R.java not generating](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2757107/1267661)?

Comment: check the edit for more info.

Comment: How are you changing the "project version"? Are you talking about the build target?

Comment: Yes, the App > Properties > Android...

Answer (score 3):

Try cleaning your project to regenerate the R file. In Eclipse this is found under Project -> Clean.

Comment: I did clean my project more then 10 times and nothing.

Comment: You could remove the project from eclipse and re-import it as well. Usually when R will not generate it's because of an error in a file in /res and R will not generate if there is an error with resources.

Comment: NO. still errors, i imported it and no R.java got generated.

Comment: Without posting your project for people to look at then there isn't much else anyone will be able to help you with

Comment: check the edit answer for some more info.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're importing the correct R files and not android.R