# Can't retrieve view with findViewById

Tags: java, android, eclipse, null, findviewbyid

I'm very new to Android. I did read many Tutorials, and also the Google example about building first app.

I was able to correctly run the app only once! The problem is as written in the title of this question. I checked every question and answer provided here on the forum, but I can't figure what's going on.

The problem is simple. I started a new project with Eclipse and added a id to the `TextView`. When I try to get the view I receive a null pointer.

This is the XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context="com.cguida1978it.prova.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text_view"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the `MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main );

    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.text_view );

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

I checked also in the `R.java` and the `text_view` is in the id class

I try to post the error log:

```
05-03 16:04:22.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2123): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 16:04:22.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2123): Process: com.cguida1978it.prova, PID:2123
05-03 16:04:22.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2123): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cguida1978it.prova/com.cguida1978it.prova.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-03 16:04:22.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-03 16:04:22.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-03 16:04:22.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-03 16:04:22.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-03 16:04:22.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-03 16:04:22.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-03 16:04:22.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-03 16:04:22.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 16:04:22.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-03 16:04:22.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-03 16:04:22.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-03 16:04:22.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-03 16:04:22.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2123): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-03 16:04:22.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at com.cguida1978it.prova.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
05-03 16:04:22.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-03 16:04:22.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-03 16:04:22.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-03 16:04:22.729: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     ... 11 more
05-03 16:04:24.989: I/Process(2123): Sending signal. PID: 2123 SIG: 9
```

Can anyone of you explain me what could be the problem?

Is it an Eclipse issue/bug? May I reset Eclipse to default settings? When I started studying Android it worked a few times... why?? I'm a little bit confused...

Thank you very much!

**EDIT**
TheFRedFox here are my imports

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.*;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

**EDIT 2**
This is a piace of the `R.java`

```
public static final class id {
    public static final int action_settings=0x7f080002;
    public static final int container=0x7f080000;
    public static final int text_view=0x7f080001;
}
public static final class layout {
    public static final int activity_main=0x7f030000;
    public static final int fragment_main=0x7f030001;
}
```

And this is the `AndroidManifest.java`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cguida1978it.prova"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.cguida1978it.prova.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I also tried to retrieve the fragment in the `onCreate()` method using the `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById()` but also the fragment results in a null pointer!

I also tried to delete the content of `R.java` as written in one of your answer here in the forum to force Eclipse to regenerate it, but the problem persists!

I really can't figure what is going wrong here. This is a near blank-porject, created from scratch! The only edits are the addition of the `TextView` id and the lines to retrieve it in the Java code!

Oh... Maybe I did not mention (or it is not clear), I started many new projects from scratch and not modified, but the id and relative codes. Each new project has this issue!

Do you think is an Eclipse issue or ADT/AVD (virtual device) issue? Is there any other IDE I could use?

Really I'm a visually-impaired developer so, even in Eclipse I do not use the graphics designer. I always edit XML files, so I was wondering if it is easy to compile from command line and debug. I read about that in the "Getting started" Google guida. Before starting to read more deep I ask you if you would suggest it!

***EDIT 3***
The laalto answer seems to fix the problem. Inside the `MainActivity` class I found a `PlaceHolder` class that extends `Fragment` class and moving the `TextView` stuff inside the `onCreateView()` using `rootView.findViewById()` I can set the text property of the `TextView`.

Why Eclipse does not create a separate class for the fragment `fragment_main`? Instead it creates a generic class inside the `MainActivity.java`?

Do you think I should create a separate class for fragments? or use the activity class as suggested in the answer 2?

In the Google's sample they extends the `MainActivity` class using the activity bar that is a subclass of `Fragment`, but, really, I was not able to retrieve resources inside the simple `onCreate()` of the `MainActivity` class...

This is causing me a little confusion...

Thank you for all of your answer and for your further explanation... I really appreciate your effort...

Comment: `(MainActivity.java:23)`
Which is `23`rd line in `MainActivity`.

Comment: are you sure it's textview? which one is line 23?

Comment: Check again which resource ID you're referencing.

Comment: Line 23 was an access to t. I tried to set a simple text, is in that way I found a problem... I removed that line before copying here... t.setText( "test" );

Comment: What are you doing with your text view?

Comment: @xXJJJasonMokXx (and others), as I said this is a very simple example to try to find the problem with the Eclipse/ADT, so the line that is missing here (the 23) is simply an assignment t.setText( "test" ); This is the line causing the exception (because t is null).

Comment: Perhaps your fragment somehow replaces it??!

Comment: Can you show me how can I check that? You know... I'm an iOS developer, but I really like understanding Android too, I find it cool, but it is quite different in concepts :-)

Comment: See Laalto's answer, I think this will resolve your problem, and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23172981/2668136) too (it might help you to understand the issue).

Comment: Yes, it resolved! Sometimes is not easy to step-in new worlds... Even if the Google guide, in their "Building your first app" does not mention the problem of fragments... but they (if I correctly remember) retrieve resources in the sendMessage() method that is linked to the button's onClick() event... maybe this is the curcial point! the sendMessage() method is called after the fragment and its view is created on the activity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `text_view` is in the fragment layout and not in the activity layout. It won't be in the activity view hierarchy yet in `onCreate()` and `findViewById()` won't find it, returning `null`. The NPE in your stacktrace is caused by trying to invoke a method on this `null`.

Move the `findViewById()` and related code to the fragment's `onCreateView()`, calling `findViewById()` on the `rootView` inflated there.

Comment: Mmmh... Inside my activity class I found the PlaceHolder fragment class that is created in the onCreate() (inside the activity class). Actually moving the resource retrieval inside the onCreateView, the TextView is correctly retrieved and I can set it's text property. I was wondering if it is correct to use a generic PlaceHolder class. Eclipse creates only the MainActivity.java... What should it be the most correct approach?

Comment: Prefer fragments over activities. You should probably rename the generated placeholder fragment when you know what it's responsible for. [Further reading](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so I have to post an answer. ^^

Can you show us your imports. Sometimes Eclipse adds accidentally not your R class but the android's one. In this android.R class your id surely is not referenced. So you'll have to import your R class (when this is the problem).

**EDIT:**

Thanks for your imports. I have to correct myself. Your R class doesn't need to be imported as it is automatically chosen. One silly question: It is the right layout you are setting as the content view, right? When it is the right layout, I unfortunately don't know more yet. But I would give you two links to read to regenerate the R.class and/or fix some problem using adt version 22, which cause into some strange errors:

Regenerate R.class:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12195532/2625488

Problems with adt version 22:
[Eclipse error: R cannot be resolved to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642604/eclipse-error-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable/16643060#16643060)